# Let A be $\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $A_1........A_n$ be $\subset \mathbb{R}$, such that. A = $\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}A_i$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If each $A_i$ is closed in $A$, show that a given function $f:A \to B$ is continuous, if and only if the restrictions $f_{A_i} \to B$ is continuous.

I'm not sure how to go about solving this question. I know that a set is only closed if its complement is open but I don't see how that helps me here unfortunately.

Comment: The difficulty of this question depends on how much mathematical background you have. Are you are allowed to use the standard fact that a function $f:A \to B$ is continuous if and only if for every subset $C$  closed in $B$,  $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $A$? If so then it's fairly easy. You need also that a finite union of closed subsets of $A$ is closed in $A$.

Comment: Also if you know the Pasting lemma or Gluing lemma that can be used to prove this easily.

Comment: @MichaelCohen Would that mean that this wouldn't work if i was from 1 to infinity? It has to be finite?

Comment: @dk1233 Yes the index set has to be finite. However if you replaced the word "open" by "closed" throughout then the proposition would also work for an infinite index set.

Comment: @MichaelCohen Can you explain why it wouldn't work for an infinite set?

Comment: @dk1233 Essentially because an infinite union of closed subsets of $A$ need not be closed. Given a closed subset $C$ of B, $f^{-1}(C)$ is the union of the closed sets $f_{A_i}^{-1}(C)$ but if the index set is infinite we can't deduce this union is closed in $A$.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question, in particular not after receiving answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:A\longrightarrow B$ is continuous, obviously $f|_{A_i}$ is continuous for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

Now assume that all the $f|_{A_i}$, $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ are continuous, and let $x_0\in A:=\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. Let $i_1,\ldots,i_k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ be the indexes of all the sets $A_{i_j}$ such that $x_0\in A_{i_j}$.

Also, because the $A_i$ are all closed, $\mathbb{R}\setminus A_i$ are all open.
Then, if $x_0\not\in A_i$ for $i\not\in\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}$,  we can take $\delta_i\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $B(x_0,\delta_i)\cap A_i=\emptyset$. Let then $\delta_M=\min\{\delta_i :i\not\in\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}\}$. We have that $B(x_0,\delta)\cap A_i=\emptyset$ for all $i\not\in\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}$.

Let $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+$, and let $\delta_{i_j}\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $|f|_{A_{i_j}}(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in B(x_0,\delta_{i_j})\cap A_{i_j}$ and $j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$.

If we choose $\delta:=\min\{\delta_M,\delta_{i_j} : j\in\{1,\ldots,k\}\}$, then, if $x\in B(x_0,\delta)\cap A$,  $x\not\in A_i$ for all $i\not\in\{i_1,\ldots,i_j\}$ because $B(x_0,\delta)\cap A_i=\emptyset$. As $x\in A=\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$, there must exist $i_j\in\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}$ such that $x\in A_{i_j}$. Then, $x\in B(x_0,\delta)\cap A_{i_j}\subset B(x_0,\delta_{i_j})\cap A_{i_j}$, and we get that: $$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|f|_{A_{i_j}}(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$
Which concludes the proof.